# HTML version of a website from image version

Tags: html, web

IS there a way to code in HTML for a website which I have only the jpg version of it? Is there any sofware which does it? I only got the image version of it from my web designer.

Comment: The usual way is to hire a web designer who does this. There is no entirely automated process for it. What your web designer gave you is most likely a sketch of what the final product will look like - and this sounds a bit like you're trying to circumvent paying them

Answer (score 3):

**[Photoshop](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/from-psd-to-html-building-a-set-of-website-designs-step-by-step/)** (proprietary)
**[Gimp](http://www.ehow.com/how_4966621_make-using-gimp.html)** (open source)

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted because both these products have the ability to take a jpg, slice it up, and produce html.  You should google "website slice " + either gimp or photoshop for tutorials/instructions on how.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmPXL1xnGDk) on using Photoshop to slice a web page pic.